# Converting an effect on complementary-log scale to odds ratio

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, hazard, cloglog

I'm trying to figure out how "an effect of treatment (beta) = 0.5 on complementary log scale" translate into an odds ratio (with baseline risk = 0.35)...

I found the clog-log h(t) = log(-log(1-h(t))) formula but I'm not sure if that could be used here...??
Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, my understanding is that $\text{cloglog}(x) = \log( -\log(x))$. Which would make sense since it's the quantile function of the Gumbel distribution (which has CDF $F=\exp(-\exp(x))$.

We have to assume that the effect you're converting is from a univariate model with binary predictor. If so, then the algebra is quite simple, we just have to write out the estimand of the parameters:

Let the $2 \times 2$ contingency table of associations be written as:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc} 
 & Y & \bar{Y} \\\hline
X & n_{11} & n_{10} \\
\bar{X} & n_{01} & n_{00} \\
\end{array}$$

Or, it's convenient to write $p_{1} = n_{11} / (n_{11} + n_{01})$ as the risk of response in "exposed" ($X=1$) individuals and similarly $n_{01} / (n_{01} + n_{00}$ for unexposed.

And the result of the GLM fit with cloglog link and binomial variance structure:

$$\text{cloglog} \left( E[Y|X] \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$$

Now this model immediately gives rise to risk predictions:

$$F(\beta_0) = p_0$$ and $$F(\beta_1 + \beta_0)=  p_1$$

And we can simply construct the OR from the risks as follows

$$OR = \frac{\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}} {\frac{p_0}{1-p_0}}$$